# HttpRiot other linker flags issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, httprequest, linker-errors, flags

i'm developing a game which already uses httpRiot framework to communicate with a server. Now i'm also trying to add  an ad-mob library but i'm getting issues with the other linked flags, if I put the -all_load flag my ad-mob service crashes, and if I take it off HttpRiot crashes, anyone knows if there is a way to make HttpRiot work without -all_load flag?
thanks in advance.